# How can I show more than one white space character in a row in a select2 data row?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-select2

I'm using [Select2](https://select2.github.io/) and I use the `{data: [{id:1, text: "..."}]` approach to define the options. I want to format each option by grouping the substring it's made up of using more than one white space character. So something like this:

```
{data: [
    {id:1, text: "Trees     -     Oak"},
    {id:2, text: "Trees     -     Pine"},
    {id:3, text: "Seas      -     North Sea"},
    {id:4, text: "Seas      -     Baltic Sea"}
]}
```

When I do this they show up as one space in the resulting dropdown (the default HTML way of dealing with spaces). When I use `&nbsp;` instead of space they show up as the string "`&nbsp;`" in the dropdown instead of as spaces.

```
{data: [
    {id:1, text: "Trees&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Oak"},
    {id:2, text: "Trees&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Pine"},
    {id:3, text: "Seas&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;North Sea"},
    {id:4, text: "Seas&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Baltic Sea"}
]}
```

Is there a way to preserve all the spaces I define in the `text` attribute of the data item?

Comment: Why not use an actual non-breaking space character, which is `\u00a0`?

Comment: Ah, yes, I did no know about that one. I tried it and it works as well. The downside is that `\u00a0` will not be matched when you search for a space. But, besides that, it's a good alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you want to use [optgroups](https://select2.github.io/options.html#how-are-option-and-optgroup-tags-serialized-into-data-objects) instead?

```
{data: [
  {
    text: "Trees",
    children: [
      {id:1, text: "Oak"},
      {id:2, text: "Pine"},
    ]
  },
  {
    text: "Seas",
    children: [
      {id:1, text: "North Sea"},
      {id:2, text: "Baltic Sea"},
    ]
  },
]}
```

or try to add

```
white-space: pre;
```

in css-class of select's item to preserve all the whitespaces in the string.

As koenpeters said in comments,for default theme css will look like:

```
.select2-container--default .select2-results__option {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

Comment: Then try to set
white-space: pre;
in select's item css class

Comment: May be you already determined exact class' name to patch? I'll add it's name to the answer, so others who will read this, will save some time.

Comment: I used `.select2-container--default .select2-results__option`, but remember that this only works for the default theme.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the answer that Yuri Gor gave is to use `&nbsp;` and include `escapeMarkup` to the select2 creation.

```
$("#isOfTheSelectNode").select2({
    escapeMarkup: function (m) { return m; }
});
```

The drawbacks are:

- None of the html markup will be escaped, which may result in strange
  `option` elements if the text contains HTML.
- Items that contain `&nbsp;` will not be matched when you search for a space.

I think Yuri Gor's answer is better if you only want to allow multiple spaces to be rendered as such.

Comment: In your case you may use some extra html/css in your options, smth like
<span class="optgroup">Trees</span><span class="delimeter">-</span><span class="opt">oak</span>
and set in css classes desired width and text align of each segment (and style all this things as you wish)
I haven't ever used select2, but in pure html select each option may have "value" attr, so, may be, search in select2 can be configured to target this values instead of inner text? If so - you can fill values with clean text without extra tags or html entties.

Answer (score 0):

Add  `white-space: normal;`  to your style

```
.select2-container .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__rendered {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    white-space: normal;
}
```