# select2 option space not searching

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

I am using [selec2](https://select2.org/) for dropdown.

i am getting data from backend and can successfully showing in the select2. but i have some data which have more then one space in between the word. like below

```
Test&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Your&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Code
I&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Am&nbsp;&nbsp;Developer
Testing Done
```

**HTML Code**

```
<select id='my_select' style="width:300px">
        <option>Test&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Your&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Code</option>
        <option>I&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Am&nbsp;&nbsp;Developer</option>
        <option value="An">Testing Done</option>
    </select>
```

**Script**

```
$("select").select2();
```

When i am trying to search data with space it is showing `No matches found`.

[image]

i have tried this [stackoverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39679566/how-can-i-show-more-than-one-white-space-character-in-a-row-in-a-select2-data-ro) also but it is not working

please check my [jsfiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/sangrambadi/d751pyw2/).

Comment: Do you want to remove the unwanted spaces from the option text?

Comment: @Mamun no, i don't want to mess with existing data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution is to use a custom matcher that replaces the char ' ' (char code 32) with the space char that is in the select2 input which is char code 160 (don't ask me why).

[JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/471673/)

```
function mySearch(params, data) {
  params.term = params.term || '';

  term = params.term.toUpperCase().replace(/ /g, String.fromCharCode(160));
  text = data.text.toUpperCase();

  if (text.indexOf(term) > -1 ) {
    return data;
  }
  return false;
}

$('#my_select').select2({
  matcher: function(params, data) {    
    return mySearch(params, data);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Check below below fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/xdr18bo4/

Here you need to remove the `&nbsp;` and add style for #select2-my_select-results .select2-results__option in CSS. This CSS style will preserve the spaces and show them as it is in HTML UI.

```
#select2-my_select-results .select2-results__option {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `&nbsp;` you can preserve spaces using the css property `white-space: pre;`

To apply this to your example, firstly remove the `&nbsp;` and replace with spaces, then add this CSS rule:

```
#select2-my_select-results .select2-results__option {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

I've updated your jsfiddle, you can view it here: https://jsfiddle.net/d751pyw2/91/

Comment: can you put in a jsfidller or plunker ?

Comment: @SangramBadi I have edited my answer with a jsfiddle link

Answer (score 0):

Using JS, create a callback function to the `matcher` property in `select2`. The following returns results when searched with single/multiple spaces.

[select2 Docs for Reference](https://select2.org/searching)

```js
$("select").select2({
    matcher : function(params,data){
        if(!params.term) return data;
        else
        {
            var text = data.text.toLowerCase(), term = params.term.toLowerCase();
            if(text.replace(/\b\s+\b/g," ").indexOf(term)>-1) return data;
            if(text.replace(/\s/g," ").indexOf(term)>-1) return data;
            return null;
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<select id='my_select' style="width:300px">
    <option>Test   Your   Code</option>
    <option>I    Am  Developer</option>
    <option value="An">Testing Done</option>
</select>
```